# How to make additional subplot of equal width as existing fixed aspect subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2 subplots the first of which has a fixed ratio. The lower subplot I don't care about the ratio but the width should align with the upper subplot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, aspect='equal', autoscale_on=False,   xlim=(0, 80), ylim=(0, 40))

ax.plot([0,10,20,40,60,70], [1,4,3,2,6,5], 'bo')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(212, xlim=(0, 8000),  ylim=(-200, 0))
ax1.plot([0,8000],[-200,0], '-')

plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I make both subplots have the same width?

**Update:**

I made it work!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

gkw = {'height_ratios':[1, 2] } 
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1,  gridspec_kw = gkw )

ax1.set_aspect('equal')
ax1.set_autoscale_on(False)
ax1.set_xlim(left=0,   right=80)
ax1.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=40)

ax1.plot([0,10,20,40,60,70], [1,4,3,2,6,5], 'bo')

ax2.set_xlim(left=0,   right=8000)
ax2.set_ylim(bottom=-200, top=0)

ya = np.diff(np.array(ax2.get_ylim()))[0] 
xa = np.diff(np.array(ax2.get_xlim()))[0] 
wa = gkw['height_ratios'][0]/float(gkw['height_ratios'][1]) 
ia = 40/80

ax2.set_aspect(float(1/wa*ia/(ya/xa)))
ax2.plot([0,8000],[-200,0], '-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The duplicate shows 5 different ways how to do it for y-coordinates, it should be quite obvious how to do it with x coordinates from that. If there is something unclear about any of those options, you may of course ask specifically about that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? 
Both subplots have the same width

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax1.set_xlim((0,80))
ax1.set_ylim((0,40))
ax1.plot([0,10,20,40,60,70], [1,4,3,2,6,5], 'bo')
ax2.set_xlim((0,8000))
ax2.set_ylim((-200,0))
ax2.plot([0,8000],[-200,0], '-')

plt.show()
```

Comment: They are the same width, but the fixed aspect ratio of the first subplot got lost.